# Confusion with #ifndef and #ifdef

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef R
   #define N1 10

   #ifndef R
      #define N2 11
   #endif


#endif

int main(){
    cout << N2 << endl;
}
```

From my understanding if `R` is not defined then `N1` will be 10.

And second case where again `R` is defined again it should not be able to define `N2` as 11, because `R` is already defined. I am just confused about it, And one Can please help to understand the point I have missed.

Comment: Why do you think `R` is defined in the second `#ifndef`?

Comment: @tkausl because #endif is not reached yeat

Comment: where is `#define R`?

Comment: As long as there is no #define R R doesn't become defined.

Comment: Looks like the inner `#ifndef R` is redundant, since you already checked `R` is not defined outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's walk through the code:

```
#ifndef R
```

`R` hasn't been defined yet, so step into the branch:

```
   #define N1 10
```

`N1` becomes 10

```
   #ifndef R
```

`R` still hasn't been defined yet, so step into nested branch

```
      #define N2 11
```

`N2` is assigned to 11

```
   #endif
```

Ends the nested branch

```
#endif
```

Ends the primary branch

So in the end `R` was never defined, so we assign `N2` successfully.

You need to explicitly `#define R` or use `-DR` in the compiler line to define `R`, it won't get defined for you within a `ifndef R` branch.

Answer (score 0):

The second `#ifndef` is redundant the way you currently have it organized. I'll write this out in a clearer pseudo code

```
IF R IS NOT DEFINED
  SET N1 = 10
  IF R IS NOT DEFINED
    SET N2 = 11
  END IF
END IF
```

This can be more simply

```
IF R IS NOT DEFINED
  SET N1 = 10
  SET N2 = 11
END IF
```

or in C/C++ preprocessor notation

```
#ifndef R
#define N1 10
#define N2 11
#endif
```